# Windows 7 pc cant access shares

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

Im having a weird issue today Im hoping someone can help me with. I manage a small domain 2000ish computers. I have three of them today that cannot access windows shares on the network. I can ping the windows server (using the server name so DNS is working), but when I try to mount, browse, etc, I get a message that the network is unreachable. Internet browsing is working just fine.

I have run a full system scan with our antivirus and with spybot and neither of them found anything of consequence( just cookies and stuff like that).

Also ipconfig /all shows everything correctly just like the other pc's that are working right.

Comment: Cant you just reimage those 3 computers?

Comment: I could but one of the computers is the CEO's computer and he would rather I try to fix is first.

Comment: These computers part of an Active Domain?  If so try adding/removing the machine from the domain.

Comment: Yes they are part of the domain. One of them I removed the computer from the domain but when I tried to add it back in I got an error that the computer could not be added to the domain because the domain controller could not be reached.

Comment: Can you still ping the Active Domain from that PC that was removed?  Be sure you ping the ip address of the server instead of its hostname.

Comment: Yes I can ping it by its ip address, by hostname, and by mydomain.local.

Comment: Can you ping the machine which you removed, which you can't add back the domain, from the domain server?  We are trying to determine, the reason, you were unable to add it back to the domain.

Comment: Yes I can ping the workstation from the domain controller.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `ipconfig /all` from one of the affected machines and from another non-affected machine.